# Android Camera 2 API black picture

Tags: java, android, api, camera

I am trying to make an app that takes a photo every time you open it without a preview.

```
    package com.example.spyer;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Size;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CamW {
    Context context;

    private static final String TAG = "CCV2WithoutPreview";

    private String mCameraId;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
    private Handler backgroundHandler;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private File file;



    public CamW(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void openCamera() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        setUpCameraOutputs();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {

            startBackgroundThread();
            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpCameraOutputs() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if (map == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                Size largest = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)), new CompareSizesByArea());
                imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
                imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start camera preview here.
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            createCameraCaptureSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

    };

    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ImageAvailable");
            backgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), file));
        }

    };

    public void closeCamera() {
        try {
            if (null != mCaptureSession) {
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != imageReader) {
                imageReader.close();
                imageReader = null;
            }
        }  finally {
            stopBackgroundThread();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        backgroundThread.start();
        backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        backgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            backgroundThread.join();
            backgroundThread = null;
            backgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCameraCaptureSession() {
        try {

            // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(imageReader.getSurface()),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            // The camera is already closed
                            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                                return;
                            }

                            // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Configuration Failed");
                        }
                    }, null
            );
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void takePicture() {
        file = getOutputMediaFile();
        try {
            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

            // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, file.toString());
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

        /**
         * The JPEG image
         */
        private final Image mImage;
        /**
         * The file we save the image into.
         */
        private final File mFile;

        public ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);

            FileOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                output.write(bytes);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
                if (null != output) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static class CompareSizesByArea implements  Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() - (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }

    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);

        File mediaStorageDir = wrapper.getDir("Test",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File test = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)+"/Dan");
        if (!test.exists())
            test.mkdirs();
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

This is the code that makes the camera take a photo. This is found on Internet and I can not manage to solve the black picture problem. Whenever this code runs it shows me a black picture. i am calling this function in MainActivity like this

```
   try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {
}

CamW c = new CamW(this);
c.openCamera();
try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
c.takePicture();
```

Comment: Do your logs show that the `ImageSaver.run()` is called? What do `mImage.getWidth()`, `mImage.getHeight()`, `mImage.getFormat()` return?